# Diameter of Graph Proof

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with maximum degree $\Delta$ and diameter $D$. How to prove that neither $\Delta$ nor $D$ can be less than $(1 + o(1)) \left(\dfrac{\log n}{\log \log n}\right)$?